# Why we are getting site content in news blog as a result of table of content web part?

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, site-collection, blog

I have added the table of content web part on my site.but I am getting site content for news Blog.How to resolve this.I don't want to get site content for a news blog.

please suggest some idea.

Comment: Try hiding it in the navigation

Answer (score 3):

It could be achieved by customizing Table Of Contents web part.

[Table Of Contents web part](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.tableofcontentswebpart(v=office.14).aspx) is XSL based web part, the following table lists and describes the two XSL files that describe the Table Of Contents Web Part:

**TableOfContentsMain.xsl**

Location: \Style Library\XSL Style Sheets\TableOfContentsMain.xsl

**Description:**

- Contains logic that generates the appropriate nodes.
- Contains functions that help designers modify the Level transforms.
- Receives all the content, parses it, and sends appropriate pieces to 
  the LevelStyle template.
- Maintains the structure of the Table of Content Web Part.

**LevelStyle.xsl**

Location: \Style Library\XSL Style Sheets\LevelStyle.xsl

**Description:** 
Contains templates that define how to display a level.

**How to render site structure using Table Of Contents web part**

Since it is not recommended to modify SharePoint out-of-the-box XSL files, we will create a custom file named SiteLevelStyle.xsl (copy of LevelStyle.xsl)

Solution: in order to exclude nodes except site nodes we are going to modify node-template template in SiteLevelStyle.xsl

To render only site nodes you could use the following code (filter to exclude non site nodes):

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(@Path) > 0 and not(contains(@Path, 'viewlsts.aspx')) and not(contains(@Path, '/Lists/')) and not(contains(@Path, '/Forms/')) and not(contains(@Path, 'WopiFrame.aspx')) and (@Title != 'Home') and (@Title != 'Recent') ">

  <!-- remaining code from node-template goes here... --> 


</xsl:if>
```

You could grab the final SiteLevelStyle.xsl file from [here](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/10109436)

**How to apply changes**

- Upload SiteLevelStyle.xsl into Style Library (/Style Library/XSL
  Style Sheets/)
- Export Table Of Contents web part
- Open web part file and specify property ItemXslLink value to /Style
  Library/XSL Style Sheets/SiteLevelStyle.xsl
- Upload the modified web part file and add imported web part on page

Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909815/how-to-make-something-like-area-contents-in-sharepoint-2013?answertab=oldest#tab-top